# Track arbitrary progress in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode

If I'm reading a book, that has 500 pages, and I'm in the page 253. I want to track that progress in Org-mode as %, is there a way to do it that is already built in (or, if is not the case, is there a plugin that allows what I want)?

Currently the ways to track progress that I know are by number of tasks done in a subtree. But in this case I won't create a task for each page, that wouln't be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make a spreadsheet like this

```
| Book      | Page | Current | Percentage |
|-----------+------+---------+------------|
| This Book |  500 |     233 |         47 |
#+TBLFM: $4=round($3*100/$2)
```

The 'Percentage' column is calculated automatically when you input new data, then press 'C-c *' to apply the formula.